# Get all values of checked checkboxes and use it on a url string

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have series of checkboxes that have values. Now what I want to do is when I click a button, I want to get all the values of the checked checkboxes and put it on the url string that I will be using. Here's some of my code.

```
<span><b>Status: </b></span>
        No arrangement yet <input type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.NoSchedule"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Proposed <input type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.Proposed"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Scheduled <input type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.Scheduled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Pend re-scheduling <input type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.RescheduledPending"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Completed <input type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.Complete"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Cancelled <input type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.Cancelled"/>
        <span style="margin-left:50px;"><button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-success">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></span>
```

Now onClick.

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
     var dateFrom = $(".dateFrom").val();
     var dateTo = $(".dateTo").val();

     window.location.href = "home/masterschedule?scheduleType=" + /*here goes the checkboxes*/ + "&dateFrom=" + dateFrom + "&dateTo=" + dateTo;
 });
```

Here's my receiving action.

```
[InPrivate]
    public ActionResult MasterSchedule(List<string> scheduleType ,string dateFrom = "", string dateTo = "")
    {
        var appointments = _appointmentRepository.All().ToList();
        var viewModel = new MasterScheduleIndexViewModel();

        if (dateFrom == "" || dateTo == "")
        {
            viewModel.Appointment = appointments;
            viewModel.DocumentPackage = _documentPackageRepository.All().Where(a => a.AMGStatus == DocumentPackageStatus.Approved || a.DocumentPackageStatus == DocumentPackageStatus.Approved).ToList();
            viewModel.AppointmentNotes = _appointmentNoteRepository.All().ToList();
            viewModel.Users = _userRepository.All().ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateFrom, "d/M/yyyy", null);
            var endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTo, "d/M/yyyy", null);

            viewModel.Appointment = appointments.Where(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.AppointmentDate, "d/M/yyyy", null) >= startDate && DateTime.ParseExact(a.AppointmentDate, "d/M/yyyy", null) <= endDate).ToList();
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I'm expecting a List of strings from the url, but would it be better if it's an array? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) i.e `$(':checkbox[name="scheduleType"]').serialize()`

This will take care of sending the `scheduleType` in the querystring
Example(`...?scheduleType=Proposed&scheduleType=RescheduledPending&scheduleType=Cancelled&dateFrom=...`)

And you can leave the `List<string> scheduleType` as it is in your action parameter.

Try

```
window.location.href = "home/masterschedule?" +
        $(':checkbox[name="scheduleType"]').serialize() + 
        "&dateFrom=" + dateFrom + "&dateTo=" + dateTo;
```

**Update**

Based on the comment you want to deserialize it to Enum List, you can just do:

In your check box cast them to `(int)` as follows.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@((int)AppointmentStatus.NoSchedule)"/>
```

and in your action change the type of your action argument to `List<AppointmentStatus> scheduleType` or as `List<int> scheduleType` (based on how you need it) instead of `List<string> scheduleType` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion but I have a problem here. The first value has "scheduleType=" string on it. The rest is good.

Comment: @ljpv14 You mean in my example right? I don't know what you have there so just typed in. Also _remember that you don't have to append `scheduleType=` in the query string as you have in your original code_

Comment: I tried serializing and received it as a list of string successfully. The problem is, the first element containts this string. "scheduleType=Scheduled", other string are good without the scheduleType= string in it.

Comment: @ljpv14 That is because you are not using the code i have. You dont need to prefix `"scheduleType=`

Comment: And also, I need to get their values, not their strings. I'm expecting numbers, not words.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't see that. Sorry for that. Thank you very much! Last question though. I need to get the values.

Comment: @ljpv14 See in your html what is `value="@AppointmentStatus.NoSchedule"` Rendered html i mean in the view source what ever is there will be passed along, i.e what serialize() does.

Comment: Yes. I thought I'm putting numbers. But it really are strings. Very well. I can work forward with this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes they are. Cast them during the assignment on the value? Or after serializing?

Comment: Will they stay as an int even if it's inside value=" " ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42447/discussion-between-psl-and-ljpv14)

Comment: Nice. This works really well. Thanks. Serializing is very flexible. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Give your checkboxes a class and you can do that:

html:

```
<span><b>Status: </b></span>
        No arrangement yet <input type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.NoSchedule" class="chk"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Proposed <input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.Proposed"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Scheduled <input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.Scheduled"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Pend re-scheduling <input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.RescheduledPending"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Completed <input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.Complete"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Cancelled <input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="scheduleType" value="@AppointmentStatus.Cancelled"/>
        <span style="margin-left:50px;"><button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-success">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></span>
```

jquery:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
     var chkValues  = '';
    $('.chk').each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
            chkValues += $(this).val();
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Just an fyi... jquery takes care of this with `serialize()` method. Also you are missing the key `scheduleType`